# Why does PyShark continue a LiveCapture with a timeout?

Tags: python, wireshark, pyshark

I mean, I suppose PyShark continues listening. My code is (within a class):

```
 def Capture(self, incoming):

    capture = pyshark.LiveCapture()
    capture.sniff(timeout=int(incoming))
    print('TIMEOUT: ' + str(int(incoming)))
    print(capture)

    print("Len" + str(len(capture)))
    pktList = [] 
    count=0
    for pkt in capture:
        count=count+1
        pktList.append([int(pkt.layers[1].version), pkt.layers[2].layer_name, pkt.length])
        print(f"Saved packet #{count}")
        print(pktList)
    print("Job is done.")
```

Output shows that despite after the timeout of 2 seconds the capture consists of a single packet, the program somehow continues reading some data. Output:

```
TIMEOUT: 2
<LiveCapture (0 packets)>
Len 0
Saved packet #1
[[4, 'tcp', '108']]
Saved packet #2
[[4, 'tcp', '108'], [4, 'tcp', '112']]
Saved packet #3
[[4, 'tcp', '108'], [4, 'tcp', '112'], [4, 'tcp', '108']]
Saved packet #4
[[4, 'tcp', '108'], [4, 'tcp', '112'], [4, 'tcp', '108'], [4, 'tcp', '112']]
Saved packet #5
[[4, 'tcp', '108'], [4, 'tcp', '112'], [4, 'tcp', '108'], [4, 'tcp', '112'], [4, 'tcp', '54']]
```

...............

How can I fix it?

Comment: _Output shows that_ _after the timeout of 2 seconds the capture consists of_ **not** _a single packet,_ `<LiveCapture (0 packets)>
Len 0`.

Comment: Did you try the code examples within my answer?

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex yes, it helped, thank you! I tried upvoting, but it won't let me yet

Comment: Instead of upvoting, you can just accept the answer.  ref: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: concerning voting ref: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to use your code, but I couldn't get it to work correctly.

I know that there are some known issues with the way that *capture.sniff(timeout=x)* works, so I put together some other code that is using *apply_on_packets* with a *timeout*.

```
import pyshark
import asyncio

packet_list = []


def process_packets(packet):
    global packet_list
    try:
        packet_version = packet.layers[1].version
        layer_name = packet.layers[2].layer_name
        packet_list.append(f'{packet_version}, {layer_name}, {packet.length}')
    except AttributeError:
        pass


def capture_packets(timeout):
    capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='en0')
    try:
      capture.apply_on_packets(process_packets, timeout=timeout)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        pass
    finally:
        global packet_list
        for item in packet_list:
            print(item)


capture_packets(2)
```

I decided to rework your code. The code below works with *capture.sniff(timeout=x)*.

```
import pyshark

packet_list = []

def capture_packets(timeout):
    global packet_list

    capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='en0')
    capture.sniff(timeout=timeout)
    packets = [pkt for pkt in capture._packets]
    capture.close()

    try:
        for packet in packets:
            packet_version = packet.layers[1].version
            layer_name = packet.layers[2].layer_name
            packet_list.append(f'{packet_version}, {layer_name}, {packet.length}')
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    finally:
        return packet_list


packets = capture_packets(2)
print(packets)
['4, tcp, 54', '6, icmpv6, 86', '6, icmpv6, 78', '4, tcp, 66']
```

I will answer any questions you have about the code examples above.

```
----------------------------------------
My system information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    macOS
Python:      3.8.0
Pyshark:     0.4.3
----------------------------------------
```