# Is .apply_on_packets 's timeout unpredictable?

Tags: python, pyshark

The following code gives unpredictable results with the following [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67234858/why-does-pyshark-continue-a-livecapture-with-a-timeout) in use:

```
import pyshark
import pandas as pd
import asyncio

def ProcessPackets(packet):
    global packet_list
    packet_version = packet.layers[1].version
    layer_name = packet.layers[2].layer_name
    packet_list.append([packet_version, layer_name, packet.length, packet.sniff_time])

def Capture(timeOrPath):
    global packet_list
    packet_list=[]
    try:
        timeout=int(timeOrPath)
        capture = pyshark.LiveCapture()          
        capture.apply_on_packets(ProcessPackets, timeout=timeout)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        pass
    except ValueError:
        capture = pyshark.FileCapture(timeOrPath)
        capture.load_packets()
        capture.apply_on_packets(ProcessPackets)
    data = pd.DataFrame(packet_list, columns=['vIP', 'protocol', 'length','timestamp']) 
    print(data['timestamp'].iloc[-1]-data['timestamp'].iloc[0])

def main(): 
    Capture(6)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Sometimes the calculated time exceeds the timeout given.
(`timestamp` is `packet.sniff_time`)

Comment: _[If a timeout is given, raises a Timeout error if not complete before the timeout (in seconds)](https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark/blob/master/src/pyshark/capture/capture.py)_
**could** be the reason? I can't figure how to fix though

Comment: FYI *capture.apply_on_packets(dosomething, timeout=timeout)* and *capture.sniff(timeout=timeout)* should not be used together, because they are doing the same thing.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex I have actually changed it since posted but this didn't help. 

I figured that the timeout given includes the processing time of `ProcessPackets()` but I couldn't solve the problem. The time is unpredictable. 
The `incoming=data['timestamp'].iloc[-1]-data['timestamp'].iloc[0]` line gives the correct value with capture from a file so the issue must be with the timeout

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex I suppose it raises the `asyncio.TimeoutError` at some point and that's when the capture stops. Other times it wouldn't go past `capture.apply_on_packets(App.ProcessPackets, timeout=timeout)`. Although, other times I'd get duration exceeding the given timeout...

Comment: can you update the question with the current code that you're using?  Also please provide more details on this:  *incoming=data['timestamp'].iloc[-1]-data['timestamp'].iloc[0]*, because I don't fully understand the issue.  Thanks.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex I've updated. As of now, I added `start = datetime.datetime.now()` at the beginning of `Capture()` and `print(datetime.datetime.now()-start)` in `except asyncio.TimeoutError:` and it gives the timeout given or with +1 sec.

It is the utterly wrong approach, though.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex I think the problem is that there is not enough time to _process+capture_ packets within the timeout due to the `apply_on_packets`'s realization. I can't use `capture.sniff(timeout=timeout)` as you [have pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67234858/why-does-pyshark-continue-a-livecapture-with-a-timeout)

Comment: I see the issue now with your code.  You combined both my previous pyshark examples into your code.   In the current state your code will have problems.   I will write up the correct code as I see it.  If it's wrong we can work on fixing it together.

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATED 06-03-2021

---

After doing some research into this capture latency issue, I have determined that the problem likely is linked to *pyshark* waiting for *dumpcap* to load.  *dumpcap* is loaded in *LiveCapture* mode

```
  def _get_dumpcap_parameters(self):
        # Don't report packet counts.
        params = ["-q"]
        if self._get_tshark_version() < LooseVersion("2.5.0"):
            # Tshark versions older than 2.5 don't support pcapng. This flag forces dumpcap to output pcap.
            params += ["-P"]
        if self.bpf_filter:
            params += ["-f", self.bpf_filter]
        if self.monitor_mode:
            params += ["-I"]
        for interface in self.interfaces:
            params += ["-i", interface]
        # Write to STDOUT
        params += ["-w", "-"]
        return params

    async def _get_tshark_process(self, packet_count=None, stdin=None):
        read, write = os.pipe()

        dumpcap_params = [get_process_path(process_name="dumpcap", tshark_path=self.tshark_path)] + self._get_dumpcap_parameters()

        self._log.debug("Creating Dumpcap subprocess with parameters: %s" % " ".join(dumpcap_params))
        dumpcap_process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(*dumpcap_params, stdout=write,
                                                               stderr=self._stderr_output())
        self._created_new_process(dumpcap_params, dumpcap_process, process_name="Dumpcap")

        tshark = await super(LiveCapture, self)._get_tshark_process(packet_count=packet_count, stdin=read)
        return tshark
```

The code above launches this on my system:

```
 /usr/local/bin/dumpcap -q -i en0 -w -
```

and this:

```
/usr/local/bin/tshark -l -n -T pdml -r -
```

I have attempted to pass in some custom parameters to *LiveCapture*

```
capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='en0', custom_parameters=["-q", "--no-promiscuous-mode", "-l"])
```

but there is still around a 1/2 of a second delay.

```
10.015577793121338
0 days 00:00:09.371264
```

In the *dumpcap* documentation there is a *-a mode*, which allows for a duration timeout, but I cannot pass that parameter into *pyshark* without causing an error.

*Tshark* also has a *-a mode*, but it also causes an error within *pyshark*

```
capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='en0', override_prefs={'': '-r'}, custom_parameters={'': '-a duration:20'})
```

There might be way to modify the timeout parameters within *pyshark* code base, to allow the *-a mode*.  To do this would require some testing, which I don't have the time to do at the moment.

I opened an [issue on this problem](https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark/issues/478) with the developers of *pyshark.*

### ORIGINAL POST 06-02-2021

---

I reworked your code to write the extracted items to a *pandas dataframe*. If this isn't what you wanted please update your questions with your exact requirements.

```
import pyshark
import asyncio
import pandas as pd

packet_list = []


def process_packets(packet):
    global packet_list
    try:
        packet_version = packet.layers[1].version
        layer_name = packet.layers[2].layer_name
        packet_list.append([packet_version, layer_name, packet.length, str(packet.sniff_time)])
    except AttributeError:
        pass


def capture_packets(timeout):
    capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='en0')
    try:
        capture.apply_on_packets(process_packets, timeout=timeout)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        pass
    finally:
        return packet_list


def main():
    capture_packets(6)
    df = pd.DataFrame(packet_list, columns=['packet version', 'layer type', 'length', 'capture time'])
    print(df)
    # output 
          packet version layer type length                capture time
    0                 4        udp     75  2021-06-02 16:22:36.463805
    1                 4        udp     67  2021-06-02 16:22:36.517076
    2                 4        udp   1388  2021-06-02 16:22:36.706240
    3                 4        udp   1392  2021-06-02 16:22:36.706245
    4                 4        udp   1392  2021-06-02 16:22:36.706246
    truncated...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The problem is that the actual capture duration differs from the timeout given. I check this by adding this line in the main: `print(df['capture time'].iloc[-1]-df['capture time'].iloc[0])`
I also changed `packet_list.append([packet_version, layer_name, packet.length, str(packet.sniff_time)])` to `packet_list.append([packet_version, layer_name, packet.length, packet.sniff_time])`.

For the timeout of 10 the result was 0 days 00:00:07.364705

Comment: It isn't _that_ important for my project actually since it's done as a part of my student curriculum, not an actual work. I believe it's an issue with pyshark

Comment: I 'fixed' it by adding `start = datetime.datetime.now()` at the beginning and `except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            print(datetime.datetime.now()-start)` which gives +- correct results. Therefore timeout must be the processing time not the capture duration

Comment: I am thinking whether it would be better to use pcapy or another way of using libpcap with python directly avoiding pyshark/tshark/wireshark. I am not familiar with it though

Comment: WOW!! There is a delay in packet processing and it ranges from .90 to .50 of a second.  This might be a bug, but I need to look in latency issues in both python and pyshark.

Comment: I looked into this more and there is a know delay in processing packets with pyshark/tshark.  This delay can be up to a second, because the application is doing various things including DNS lookups.  From what I see there is no way to reduce this delay.